# Deploying sharepoint project after coming back from future

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2013

I'm developing a web part for calendar events for Sharepoint 2013 in Visual Studio 2013. For debugging I have to switch time on my sharepoint server to see how my web part would behave on different date. But if I set my server date for some date in future and deploy my project from VS, then switch my date back to today, make some changes in my project and try to deploy it again, the code on server would stay the same as it was in the version which I deployed in the "future". If I go to my project folder I see that the folders "pkg" and "pkgobj" have that "future" date. But If I delete that folders and try to deploy my project to SP, VS says it can't find file "manifest.xml". What should I do in such situations to make VS "forget" about the projects created in the "future"?

**Edit:** Clean and rebuild didn't work, my VS and office tools are up to date, tried to manualy remove solution from SP and deploy .wsp - not helping. The only way I can update the project on server is to set my server date further in the future and deploy after that, but this is very unconvenient.

Comment: clean and rebuild did not work? btw do you use CSK dev ?

Comment: Thank you for reply! Clean and rebuilt not helping. I've tried to install CKS dev but couldn't find anything that can help me. Maybe I'm missing something? (I can't use quick deploy because for some reason it tries to deploy the whole solution which is not an option, because I have over 40 projects in it, including projects with data struct)